# hard to understand Open Ball in Standard Discrete Metric Space

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification, proof-explanation

$$B_{\epsilon}(x)=\cases{\{x\} & $0<\varepsilon \le 1$\\
X & $\varepsilon > 1$}$$

[image]

[Open Ball in Standard Discrete Metric Space](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Open_Ball_in_Standard_Discrete_Metric_Space)

**Is this proof wrong?**
I have no trouble understanding the first half of the proof, which for all $x$ and $a$ with a distance greater than $1$ is not in the open ball with a radius less than $1$ and such open ball contains the centre element itself. However, in the second half, just so wired that $$\forall x\in A:d(x, a)>\epsilon\implies x\in B_{\epsilon}(a;d)$$ How does two elements distance greater than $\epsilon$ and one element will fall in the open ball that centre at the other elements with a radius less than the distance? Is this constructive approach wrong?

I know what the discrete metric is

Appreciate any comments

Comment: It is just  simple typo. $d(x,a) >\epsilon$ should have been $d(x,a) <\epsilon$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're being overly formal IMO.

Let $0 < \varepsilon \le 1$.

Then $y \in B_\varepsilon(x)$ iff $d(x,y) < \varepsilon \le 1$ so $d(x,y) <1$ and as the only  values of $d$ are $0$ and $1$ it follows that $d(x,y)=0$ so that $y=x$. So $y \in B_\varepsilon(x) \iff y= x$ which in sets is just $B_\varepsilon(x)=\{x\}$.

If $\varepsilon > 1$, we have for all $y \in X$ that $d(x,y) \le 1 < \varepsilon$ so $y \in B_\varepsilon(x)$ holds for any $y$ or in sets again $B_\varepsilon(x)=X$.